# Finding selector form random link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I don't know how to find which item link was clicked.
I have webpage http://demo.opencart.com/ and I choose product and go to compare product, I use random to click "add to cart", and I neet do check that the price of item I click "add to cart" is the same price as in cart.

```
public void chooseRandomItem() {
    List <WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@value = \"Add to Cart\"]"));
    Random gen = new Random();
    WebElement link = links.get(gen.nextInt(links.size())); 
    link.click();
```

It's work, but now I dont know which "add to cart" was clicked, and I cant compere it with price in cart. How should i solve it?

________________________UPDATED__________________________

To simulate:

1. go to http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=ipod
2. clickt "compare item" under the item
3. click url "product compare"

   4. choose one random item and click "add to cart"
   5. check that the price in cart is the same as i choose (random) item price

and now i choose random link, and I have to compare price of this random item with price in cart

Comment: I'm confused by your scenario. You originally state that you clicked "add to cart" but weren't sure which one you clicked to compare to the price in cart but the UPDATED section is talking about product compare. Will you please clarify your scenario and update the steps? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, sorry maybe i wasnt precisious.  My right scenario is in UPDATED section. I stoped on comparing the price.  The code in 1st post choose random item from compare items and click "add to cart". When i do this, in cart there is info about value of item in this cart. I now I need to compare price of the item i random add to cart and price "on" cart

Comment: I don't really agree with this 'click random thing' approach, because how can you truly verify the results? You should ensure the data you need is present (load it, else clear and recreate), click real things with confidence, and thus be able to verify fully.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is all in an HTML table, it makes it a bit harder. What I would do is:

1. Count the number of table columns (`totColumns`). Do this by counting the `TD`s in a `TR` in the HTML `TABLE`.
2. Get a random number (`r`) between 2 and `totColumns`. You can google this easily.
3. Get the price from column `r` and click the Add to Cart link in column `r`. You know which row holds the price, just grab `TD` #`r` from that row. Do the same for the Add to Cart link row and click it.

Now you can compare the price found on the Product Comparison page to the price in the cart.

---

EDIT: Slight change after thinking about this some more and added some details.

Comment: can You tell me something more how to do this?

Comment: Added some details and changed the logic a little to make it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention, I would *wrap* the link and the price (or even more information) into a kind of product-ui-element for better structure in code.

First you get all products as collection and choose one randomly as you like. Second you fetch the information for this concrete product.

```
    var products = WebDriver.FindAdaptedElements(By.CssSelector("div.product-thumb")); 

    // do your random selection
    var product = products.ElementAt(???); // do your random selection

    // get product related elements - the price:
    var price = product.FindAdaptedElement(By.CssSelector("p.price")).Text;

    // add to cart
    product.FindAdaptedElement(By.CssSelector("div.button-group>button")).Click();
    // .. do the checks ..
```

In the next step you can use the *price* variable (string) to verify the correct amount for that product.